# Response completes before response.redirect can occur in an async method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

This is in an mvc application.  The user navigates to a view. In that view an async method is called with `await` and if certain conditions are met `response.redirect` is called.  However, the response completes before the awaited method completes.

Is there a way to stop the response from completing?

Comment: please share your code. a [mcve] would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
var whateverTask = Task.Run(async () => await yourTask;
taskList.Add(whateverTask);
Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait();
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  This does cause the response to wait for the task to finish.  But the redirect is still failing.  I'll look into that part.

Comment: Ah, your solution worked great.  I forgot that I overwrote OnComplete which wasn't letting the redirect go through.